# simple sql query. how to solve it..?

Tags: sql

```
ID  MOBILE
1   9869600733
2   9869600793
3   9869600799
```

all id whose mobile number containing 9 three times... ?

Comment: WHICH RDBMS are you using? general idea is replace 9 with ``(empty value not whitespace), and count the data length before and after, if = 3, then they are the candidate rows xD

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LONG exactly what i thought too

Comment: @EstebanP. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your RDBMS is needed to know the EXACT solution, but this works for most. I used `MOBILE_ID_TABLE` because you didn't provide table name. Depending on your RDBMS LIKE will want `%` or `*`.

```
SELECT ID FROM MOBILE_ID_TABLE WHERE MOBILE LIKE '%9%9%9%';
SELECT ID FROM MOBILE_ID_TABLE WHERE MOBILE LIKE '*9*9*9*';
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution would be:

the statement will return all records, where the MOBILE column includes three times the number 9.

```
SELECT *
  FROM youtable
 WHERE (LEN(MOBILE) - LEN(REPLACE(MOBILE,'9',''))) = 3
```

Comment: less efficient than mine. xDDD